# Android Storage access framework does not work on Android 11 (API 30)

Tags: android

I use the following code to check wether "Storage access framework" is available:

```
  public static boolean isSafAvailable(@Nullable final Context context)
  {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)
      try
      {
        if (context == null)
          return true;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        return intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null;
      }
      catch (final Exception ex)
      {
        return true;
      }
    return false;
  }
```

This works perfectly for target sdk versions smaller than 30. For target version 30 on Android 11 (API 30) 'intent.resolveActivity' always returns null, so it says storage access framework is not available. What am I doing wrong? Do I need any additional permissions or do I run in a problem with 'package visibilit' on API 30?

Comment: Just start your intent. Why should you try to resolve something?

Comment: `if (context == null)
          return true;` ??? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In Android 11 you need follow package visibility guide & add the `queries` in your manifest just outside the `applcation` tag.

For your case it would be:

```
<application>
<!--Your application code-->
    </application>
    <!--add this here-->
    <queries>
        <!--
             Specific intents you query for,
             eg: for a custom share UI
        -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_DOCUMENT" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

I would also suggest that you read this good blog: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9

Comment: A lot of fuss if this was true to be able to use ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT. `eg: for a custom share UI` There is nothing custom to this action. And would you add a queries to for ACGION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE and others? Luckily i can do without.